# Using AddViewField in SharePoint Rest API to add multiple columns in list view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

I have followed various google search that have allowed me to create a list view (for a SP List) using the REST API through Power Automate.

I then managed to delete the columns (all of them). Finally I want to add back multiple columns.

My question is - is there a way to add multiple columns in one REST API call?

This fails (attempting 2 columns in an array):

[image]

This works (just adding one column):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint REST API does not provide an option to add multiple fields to the view in one call.

A similar post for your reference:
[Create SharePoint 2013 list view with ViewFields using REST API](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/80e606fb-e804-419f-8c07-ecc1721bc771/create-sharepoint-2013-list-view-with-viewfields-using-rest-api?forum=sharepointdevelopment)