# SP 2013 REST API: set list view column order

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a list view in which I need to change the column order every quarter of the year. Is there a method using rest API to set all my visible columns to a specific order, and then add a new one and drop an old one each quarter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can edit your view to add, move or remove fields with SharePoint REST API. It's working for both on-premise, including SharePoint Server 2013 and later, and SharePoint Online in Microsoft 365.

Sample of requests:

##### Get current view fields (GET)

```
GET https://your-webapp/sites/your-site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('YourList')/views/getByTitle('All%20Items')/viewFields
```

##### Add a field from a view (POST)

```
POST https://your-webapp/sites/your-site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('YourList')/views/getByTitle('All%20Items')/viewFields/addViewField
'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'

{ "strField": "Status" }
```

##### Remove a field from a view (POST)

```
POST https://your-webapp/sites/your-site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('YourList')/views/getByTitle('All%20Items')/viewFields/removeViewField
'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'

{ "strField": "Status" }
```

##### Remove all fields from a view (POST)

```
POST https://your-webapp/sites/your-site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('YourList')/views/getByTitle('All%20Items')/viewFields/removeAllViewFields
'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
```

##### Change field order from a view (POST)

```
 POST https://your-webapp/sites/your-site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('YourList')/views/getByTitle('All%20Items')/viewFields/moveViewFieldTo
'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'

{ "field": "Status", "index": 2 }
```

Screenshots (with SharePoint Online & Power Automate):
[image: requests]
[image: responses]
[image: results]

Sources:

- [Interface ViewFieldCollection](https://dattabase.com/docs/sprest/interfaces/_lib_sp_entitytypes_d_.viewfieldcollection.html)
- [SP.ViewFieldCollection Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj247025(v=office.15))
- [Create SharePoint 2013 list view with ViewFields using REST API](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/80e606fb-e804-419f-8c07-ecc1721bc771/create-sharepoint-2013-list-view-with-viewfields-using-rest-api?forum=sharepointdevelopment)
- [Using AddViewField in SharePoint Rest API to add multiple columns in list view](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/284364/using-addviewfield-in-sharepoint-rest-api-to-add-multiple-columns-in-list-view)
- [SharePoint REST moveviewfieldto endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1287894/sharepoint-rest-moveviewfieldto-endpoint)

Comment: Wow!!! Fantastic!  Thank you

Comment: Sorry. Correction. Can you tell me what the headers are for this Post?

Comment: Oh sorry, I updated my answer with headers and screenshots.