# SharePoint Rest API: MoveViewFieldTo syntax error

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, list-view

I am trying to move a field in a listview but I am getting the "invalid" error below. I'm using Alteryx, so the setup is not like a normal JS script.

I have used moveViewFieldTo but I have also seen moveFieldTo. Which is correct?

Is my JSON syntax incorrect?

The expression `\"web/lists/getByTitle('zTestList')/views/getByTitle('All%20Items')/viewFields/MoveViewFieldTo('field':'TodaysDate','index': 0)\" is not valid."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is wrong, `field` and `index` must be part of the body, not the path:

```
POST https://your-webapp/sites/your-site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('zTestList')/views/getByTitle('All%20Items')/viewFields/moveViewFieldTo
'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'

{ "field": "TodaysDate", "index": 0 }
```

Sources:

- [SP 2013 REST API: set list view column order](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310392/sp-2013-rest-api-set-list-view-column-order)
- [SharePoint REST moveviewfieldto endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1287894/sharepoint-rest-moveviewfieldto-endpoint)